# How to show multiple LINE_STRIPs?

Tags: ros, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to show the boundaries of the road.
The boundary has many points, I use LINE_STIP to do this. But as the road has two boundaries, although I give them different id, RViz still connect the end point of boundary1 to the start point of boundary2.
Is there any method to make boundary1 and boundary2 not connect with each other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261913/how-to-show-multiple-line_strips?/) by [Ben Chern](https://answers.ros.org/users/30422/ben-chern/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to do so is by creating two separate LINE_STRIP markers, inserting them both in a [MarkerArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/MarkerArray.html) and publishing that. There are a few sentences about the MarkerArray in the [rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Example_Usage_.28C.2B-.2B-.2BAC8-roscpp.29) page, but there doesn't seem to be a specific tutorial. Anyhow, it's identical to how you deal with Markers, but you have to publish a MarkerArray now and load the corresponding plugin in RVIZ.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben Chern](https://answers.ros.org/users/30422/ben-chern/) on 2017-05-17**:
In my previous code, I just use one marker and give it different id every time. It seems it doesn't work. I tried to create two markers, and each publishes a line_strip. Now they are not connected in RViz. Thanks for your suggestion.